# easy calculus hw question on computing work from spring compression

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

hw question reads:
A 5-kg mass is attached to a spring that hangs vertically and is stretched 3 m from the
equilibrium position of the spring. Assume a linear spring with F(x) = kx. How much
work is required to compress the spring and lift the mass 1.5 m? Round to four decimal
places when appropriate.

my attempt:
https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJx9jkEKwjAQRfeCdxiyStpSFSko0guIrly4DpqmIW1Tkln0-E6KtkXEXWbm_5eny2N-OK1XFkooEr3Z07vig6DRJgMNd-ftrfem07QyHSrtJSoeMxkMGWwz2OWFoGSNbcMZSqsCMEghoOdzW9CGwRnQwcO1vVchANYKwnhl4v3VVYZwMRWOOgRO9B_yJ7xgN7EbuS3d2ELLoWzA_O6n8O1JsIkWSSC75-w9Ob8AoxtggA==&lang=sage

my concern is that the solutions manual provided shows the answer to be 
128.625 J what am I missing here ?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**
The spring *helps* you lift the weight, since it is stretched when you begin stretching it.

Comment: can we assume we are computing the work as we compress from the object hanging 3 ft to the object only hanging 1.5 feet from equilibrium? or are we compressing from equilibrium to further up 1.5 feet in which case the spring is acting against you, not helping you... from reading the question i assumed it was the latter,  is this not the case?